# How can I take first word in comma separated string using regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to take the first comma seperated value from that string.

```
"Lines.No;StartPos=3;RightAligned;MaxLength =2"
```

I used `"\b.*\;"` regex to take `"Lines.No"`. But the result is

```
"Lines.No;StartPos=3;RightAligned;"
```

thanks.

Comment: last time I checked ";" was a semi-colon.

Comment: You say "first comma separated value", but don't you mean "first semicolon separated value"?

Comment: The last time I checked, semicolon wasn't spelled with a hyphen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, anchor the search at the start of the string. Then use a lazy quantifier: `^\b.*?;` or a negated character class: `^\b[^;];`

But careful: Could semicolons appear in your CSV fields (in quoted strings)? If so, regexes can still be made to work, but will be a lot more complicated - a CSV parser would be much better.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. 
But the result is like that;
Lines.No;\n
StartPos=3;\n
RightAligned;

Comment: OK, you probably need to make sure that the regex engine is anchored at the beginning of the string. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know you are looking fore a regex, but if you have delimited string, use your favourite language's split() function, eg in Python

```
>>> s="Lines.No;StartPos=3;RightAligned;MaxLength =2"
>>> s.split(";")[0]
'Lines.No'
```

Much simpler than regex. Similarly, explode() in PHP, split() in Perl, Split() in C# , etc

Comment: +1. I think using `split` in this case makes the code a little cleaner. Even simple regular expressions make the code a little more obtuse, and I'd much rather see operations expressed in more explicit constructs if possible. Regex has its place, but not as a substitute for a simple split().

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way too, in python

```
>>> x="Lines.No;StartPos=3;RightAligned;MaxLength =2"
>>> x[:x.find(";")]
'Lines.No'
```